# Elm Http Api call

Tags: http, elm

I'm fairly new to Elm. I'm currently trying to teach myself how to make API calls in Elm. The program I'm making is very simple, it makes an http request to fetch some Trello card info and display it. My program compiles but nothing happens when I click the button to fetch the information. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong please help. Thanks

```
 module Main exposing (..)

import Html exposing (..)
import Html.Attributes exposing (..)
import Html.Events exposing (..)
import Http
import Json.Decode as Decode


main : Program Never Model Msg
main =
    program
        { init = init
        , view = view
        , update = update
        , subscriptions = subscriptions
        }


type alias Model =
    { boardName : String
    , cardName : String
    }


init =
    ( Model "Default Board" "Default Card"
    , Cmd.none
    )



-- UPDATE


type Msg
    = CardFetch (Result Http.Error String)
    | FetchCard


update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        FetchCard ->
            ( model, getCardName )

        CardFetch (Ok incomingName) ->
            ( Model model.cardName incomingName, Cmd.none )

        CardFetch (Err _) ->
            ( model, Cmd.none )



-- HTTP


getCardName =
    Http.send CardFetch (Http.get "https://api.trello.com/1/members/..." decodeCard)


decodeCard =
    Decode.at [ "data", "card", "name" ] Decode.string



--UPDATE
-- VIEW


view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    div []
        [ div []
            [ button [ onClick FetchCard ] [ text "Get Card" ] ]
        , div [ class "card" ]
            [ h3 [] [ text model.cardName ]
            , div [ class "board" ] [ h4 [] [ text model.boardName ] ]
            ]
        ]



-- SUBSCRIPTIONS


subscriptions : Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model =
    Sub.none
```

Comment: You are absorbing all errors that may have occurred in the Err CardFetch case. Try writing the error message to the screen or use Debug.log to print it to the browser console.

Comment: Thanks that's very helpful. I got the following error in the console:
Errors: { type = "node", branches = [] }

I'm guessing I didn't configure the structure of the json I'm expecting back well. Do you know how to reference a value in  a json object that has the shape of :
[
{ data : {
    card : { name: ... }
    }
},
{},
{}
]

I'm trying to reach the name value. Thanks

Comment: Can you post an example of the json you expect from that endpoint with your question?

Comment: sure here:
[
  {
    "id": "",
    "idmc: "",
    "data": {
      "check": {
        "state": "",
        "name": "",
        "id": ""
      },
      "check": {
        "name": "",
        "id": ""
      },
      "card": {
        "link": "",
        "idS\": ,
        "name": "",
        "id": ""
      },
      "board": {
        "link": "",
        "name": "",
        "id": ""
      }
    },
    "type": "",
    "date": "",
    "mc": {
      "id": "",
      "ahash": "",
      "fn": "",
      "initials": "",
      "user": ""
    }
  },
  {...},
  {...}
]

Comment: Finally figured it out. I had to decode it as an array with 
Decode.index 0 ( Decode.at [ "data", "card", "name"] Decode.string)

Comment: Your decoder here was pretty simple, but consider using http://json2elm.com to automatically convert example JSON to a Elm decoders to avoid problems like this . Also, can you post an answer and accept it to close this question?

Comment: Thanks @AhmedFasih I will give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured it out. I had to decode it as an array with Decode.index 0 ( Decode.at [ "data", "card", "name"] Decode.string)